# Accessing C# variable from Javascript in asp.net mvc application

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a problem in `How to use javascript variables in C# and vise versa` : I have this `Model` passing to the view:

```
public List<Tache> Get_List_Tache()
{
    Equipe _equipe = new Equipe();
    List<Tache> liste_initiale = _equipe.Get_List_tache();
    return liste_initiale;
}
```

It's a list of objects `Tache` in which I'd like to use it's three fields `Tache_description`, `Begin_date` and `End_date`.

In my JavaScript code I have this function and it works fine:

```
       <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var date = new Date();
            var d = date.getDate();
            var m = date.getMonth();
            var y = date.getFullYear();

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                theme: true,
                header: {left: 'prev,next today',center: 'title',right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'},
                editable: true,
                events: [
                         @foreach (var m in Model.Get_List_Tache())
                          {
                        @:{title : @m.Tache_description , start: @m.Begin_date , end :  @m.Begin_date }
                          }
                        ]

                });
                                        });

</script>
```

The values of the array `events` are just for test, and I need to fill `events` by the value of the `Model`. For each element like this: `title = Tache_description`, `start = Begin_date` and `end = End_date`.

So how can I do this task? Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there anyway you could return a JSON result, and perhaps make a call to the data that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a foreach razor loop within javascript :

```
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    theme: true,
    header: {left: 'prev,next today',center: 'title',right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'},
    editable: true,
    events: [
    @
    {
      bool isFirst = true;
    }
    @foreach(var m in Model)
    {
        if(!isFirst)
        {
          @:,
        }

        @:{title: @m.Tache_description, ...<other properties here>}

        isFirst = false;
    }
    ]
});
```

Comment: but it indicates an error of syntax in the `comma` in  `@:{title: @m.Tache_description, start: @m.Begin_date, end :  @m.Begin_date } `

Comment: Yep you need to check if the item is first or not, if it is not first add a commar before "{"

Comment: sorry i don't understand what order ?

Comment: Look at the updated answer, it has a sample code for checking it

Comment: with no change :( the same result

Comment: You are probably missing quotes around strings, @:{title: "@m.Tache_description", ...<other properties here>}

Comment: can you post the generated javascript?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33536/discussion-between-lamloumi-and-alexandr-mihalciuc)

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
foreach (var item in YourList)
{
    events: [{ title: '@item.title', start: '@item.start', end: '@item.end'}]
}
```

So, in this code just replace name your model entity.

Comment: but the model is a list of Tache(description,begin,end)

Answer (score 2):

For title, you can do title = "@Tache_description"

Not sure about the format/type of your Begin_date and End_date, you may need some function to read the date into a javascript format. Shouldnt be that hard.

Loop through each element and add the elements to the events array. It is something like...

```
events = new Array()
@foreach(tache in list){
    item = { blah : blah, blah : blah };
    events.push(item);
}
```

for each c# item in this c# list, write these lines of javascript. You may end up with a very long javascript code block, but it should do the trick. Above is pseudocode.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Darin's answer: If you need the server-side variables in an external JavaScript file, take a look this blog post: [Generating External JavaScript Files Using Partial Razor Views](http://blog.mariusschulz.com/generating-external-javascript-files-using-partial-razor-views)

Answer (score 1):

1: if your model is expecting the list of `Tache` then you have the whole list you can manipulate.

2: you can get the data using jquery ajax as json data by calling your action `Get_List_Tache()`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this javascript is inline in your page you could do the following:

```
@model IList<Tache>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var events = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Select(x => new { title = x.Description, start = x.Begin.ToString("o"), end = x.End.ToString("o") })));

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        theme: true,
        header: { 
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        events: events
    });
</script>
```

This example assumes that your Tache model has properties `Description`, `Begin` and `End`:

```
public class Tache
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime Begin { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}
```

And if this script is in a separate javascript file you could still set a global `events` variable in your view which will later be used by your script. Alternatively you could fetch this model using an AJAX call.

Comment: I have a problem here `(x => new {` : it didn't accept the lambda expression

Comment: Try putting it on the same line. I have updated my answer. Also make sure that you have used the correct property names on your Tache model in the lambda expression. And by the way if Visual Studio underlines this with red squiggle as error you can ignore it. Visual Studio Intellisense is not intelligent enough. Run your application and see if it works.

Comment: the same this error appears : `CS1977: Can not use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically distributed free by first cast to delegate type or kind of expression tree operation`

Comment: This should work unless your code is different than what I have shown in my answer. Is your view strongly typed to `@model IList<Tache>`. I hope you are not attempting to use some ViewBag stuff.

Comment: What is the reason of this error `CS1977: Can not use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically distributed free by first cast to delegate type or kind of expression tree operation` ?

Comment: The reason is that your model is not `@model IList<Tache>` or your expression is different than what I have showed in my answer. This error is a very strong indication that you attempted to use a Select LINQ query on a dynamic variable such as `ViewBag` instead of using the `Model` as shown in my answer. What I have showed in my answer works. I have tested it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33555/discussion-between-lamloumi-and-darin-dimitrov)