# Converting Datetime C# type to Date javascript in asp.net mvc razor application

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem in converting date in javascript . i try this snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var date = new Date();
            var d = date.getDate();
            var m = date.getMonth();
            var y = date.getFullYear();

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                theme: true,
                header: {left: 'prev,next today',center: 'title',right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'},
                editable: true,
                events: [
                            {
                    title: 'Birthday Party',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 19, 0),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 22, 30),
                    allDay: false
                    }
                        ]

                });
            });
```

and it works, but if i change it to:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var date = new Date();
            var d = date.getDate();
            var m = date.getMonth();
            var y = date.getFullYear();

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                theme: true,
                header: {left: 'prev,next today',center: 'title',right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'},
                editable: true,
                events: [
                         @foreach (var m in Model.Get_List_Tache())
                          {
                        @:{ title: "Tache_description", start: new Date(@m.Begin_date.Year +"," + @m.Begin_date.Month +","+ @m.Begin_date.Day ) , end: new Date( @m.End_date.Year +"," +@m.End_date.Month +"," + @m.End_date.Day ) }
                          }
                        ]

                });
            });
```

There is a syntaxic error in the format of date.

So what is the reason of this error? How can i fix it?

Comment: try replace those `","` with just `, `

Comment: I don't get the string concatenation going on there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing C# variable from Javascript in asp.net mvc application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17671385/accessing-c-sharp-variable-from-javascript-in-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: Why are you using a foreach? I don't think it would like it if you tried to set those properties twice.

Comment: Do a 'view source'. I suspect that your loop is outputting invalid JavaScript.

Comment: @krillgar because the model contains a list

Comment: OK, I get what that's doing now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still with FosterZ, but you should also get rid of the `+` as well.

So instead of

```
start: new Date(@m.Begin_date.Year +"," + @m.Begin_date.Month +","+ @m.Begin_date.Day ) ,
```

try

```
start: new Date(@m.Begin_date.Year , @m.Begin_date.Month , @m.Begin_date.Day ) ,
```

If that still doesn't work, then view the source of the page, and see what is being put into the Javascript there. It's most likely not what you're expecting it to be. If you can't figure it out, add that to your question and we can take a look at it.

Comment: Almost! Remember to -1 to the month as months in JavaScript start at 0 and not 1 like C# DateTime

Answer (score 8):

You can use this solution

`start: new Date(@m.Begin_date.ToString("yyyy,MM-1,dd"))`

Comment: var date = new Date(@DateTime.ToString("yyyy,MM-1,dd,HH,mm,ss"))

Answer (score 1):

You can just use c#'s DateTime.ToLongDateString() and pass it into the constructor of the Date object in javascript as long as you want the date as is without modification.

```
 start: new Date(@m.Begin_date.ToLongDateString());
```